# How to use a symbol as an option value in a select element in a react component

Tags: reactjs, symbols

I'm trying to set up a part of my program to use symbols much like a C# enum as per below but the value is always blank. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
const options = [
    {
        display: 'option1',
        value: Symbol('option1')
    },
    {
        display: 'option2',
        value: Symbol('option2')
    },
    {
        display: 'option3',
        value: Symbol('option3')
    },
];

const SymbolSelect = () => {
    return (
        <Select>
            {options.map(({ value, display }, i) => (
                <option value={value} key={i}>{display}</option>
            ))}
        </Select>
    );
}
```

Comment: The `value` attribute of an `<option>` only allows strings or numbers, not `Symbol` objects. What would be the advantage of using `Symbol` like in the example anyways? Note, that `Symbol('foo') === Symbol('foo')` is `false`.

Comment: It's the same value as using a symbol over a string, it's exact, not subject to typos and can not be confused with a similar string.

Comment: You could as well define some constants that actually are strings and use them instead of string literals everywhere else you need them. Javascript is not type safe so if you want to prevent incorrect usage of defined types your are better off using typescript and define your types there.

Comment: It's as you said above ``Symbol('foo') !== Symbol('foo')``. I don't want them to be equal.
I do not want ``const options1 = { foo: Symbol('bar') };`` and ``const options2 = { foo: Symbol('bar') };`` to be equal.

Comment: `{foo: 'bar'} === {foo: 'bar'}` is also `false`.

Comment: yea but ``options1.foo === options2.foo`` is ``true``